# CPU soft lockup on GCP - KVM on Centos

Tags: google-compute-engine, cpu, centos7

For the past couple of weeks I am seeing this softlockup issue on GCP. VM gets extremely slow and CPU utilization rate is normal. Has anyone seen this recently, is there any debugging I can do to get to the bottom of this[CPU Utilization chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWl1x.png)

Message from syslogd@testbed-6 at Feb 13 20:40:46 ...
 kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#11 stuck for 22s! [qemu-kvm:1547]
[Error logs][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4cgW.png)

System info:
Using the latest centos image https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/centos-cloud/global/images/family/centos-7

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you have a CPU utilization issue on GCP Virtual Machine (VM) instances, the CPU issue could be by exceeding the IOPS and throughput limits, you can check the limits on GCP disks (standard or SSD persistent disk) according to following [tables](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance#cpu_count_size), check the "Disk I/O bytes and Disk I/O (operations)"[graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejnCo.png) in the monitoring section on your VM instance and if you exceed the suggested values, [Resize your persistent disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd) to increase the IOPS and throughput limits.

Greetings.

Aldo.